# can't get access to ArrayLists of ArrayList (generic)

Tags: java, generics

I wrote class that represent a Set. in the Set i have a field "elements" of ArrayList. all the methods in the class are generics.

first method i wrote is a method that get another Set as argument and returns new Set that hold the union between this.Set to the argument. here is the method:

```
   public Set<E> union(Set<E> s){
      Set<E> toReturn = new Set<>();

      for(E toAdd : this.elements) {
        toReturn.addToSet(toAdd);
      }
      for(E toAdd : s.elements)
        toReturn.addToSet(toAdd);

      return toReturn;
   }
```

Now i want to write another method that get as argument ArrayList> and returns new Set that represent the union between this.Set to all the Sets inside the argument ArrayList. but i can't get access to the Sets inside the ArrayList. here is my code:

```
   public Set<E> union(ArrayList<Set<E>> s) {
      Set<E> toReturn = new Set<>();

      for(E el : s) {
               toReturn.addToSet(s.union(el));
      }

      return toReturn;
   }
```

The compiler tell me "The method union(E) is undefined for the type ArrayList>.

I'll be happy for some help. Thanks

Comment: Why do you pass in an ArrayList of a Set<E>? Why not simply pass in a List<E>?

Comment: Share the code of the class with the attributs to avoid misunderstanding please

Comment: Are you sure you are no confusing `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.Set` with your code ?

Comment: Did you name your class `Set` ?  You should never use a build-in name

Comment: @azro Since the class that the OP designed represents exactly a Set, `Set` should be its name.

Comment: @Kröw  nope, a class should NEVER be named with an existing name to avoid confusion, and what is he need à util.Set in its Set class ? If you have now idea use OwnSet or MySet at least

Comment: @azro That’s stupid. The class the OP designed represents a Set, so it should be named `Set`. If there’s any “confusion” between the standard library’s and the OP’s classes, then more absolute class references can be used (e.g. `java.uril.Set`). If anything, naming it something other than `Set` would cause confusion, and calling it something like `MySet` is terrible in practice, and confusing. (Imagine working with a team and realizing that the reason you couldn’t find the Set class you’ve been searching 30 minutes for was because it `My` in front of the name.)

Comment: @Kröw call that stupid if you want but use an existing name is **never** a good idea.

Comment: @azro It's a good idea if that name is what the class represents.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable in the for loop, s is the ArrayList, and toReturn is the set that you want to calculate the union of, with the **addAll(otherSet);** method. You may be using the Guava's Set library if so, you can keep using the union(otherSet) method.

Where you have:

```
for(E el : s) {
               toReturn.addToSet(s.union(el));
      }
```

Better put:

```
for(Set<E> el : s) {
               toReturn.addToSet(toReturn.union(el));
      }
```

Comment: yes i called my class "Set" because i have to realize the Set class. i changed the line to "toReturn.addToSet(toReturn.addAll(el));" but its still tell me "the method addAll(int) is undefined for the type Set<E>. I think i have to add cast to "toReturn". but i dont know how...

Comment: Then try: for(Set<E> el : s) {... So the compiler knows that el is a set.